# Can not Undo After use Replacing Tool in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

When using NetBeans , for some reason when I changed the counter of a for loops- (I replaced the character 'i' with character 'a' ) using Replacing Option (Save my Project and Closed )

After opening again I realize that all characters `'i'` in any position in the Project replaced with `'a'`
, because there are build in files and words with both 'i' and 'a' , I could not replace these 2 characters again

Screen-shot from Code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp9r6.png

Is there a way or some how of saved backup or any thing can I do to correct this problem ?!

Comment: ..the wording here is difficult. Pleaes add screenshot and help us to see, just what exactly is going wrong. All I see is "something got replaced and I can't go back" but I'm lost otherwise

Comment: It become Some Thing like that : http://i.stack.imgur.com/NASsk.png @Coffee

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans has [local history support](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/LocalHistory/) enabled by default

To access the local history of a file, open it in your editor, go to `Team`->`History`->`Show History`.

Unfortunately, you can't revert the entire project at once (you should use a version control system for that), but you might access the entire history Netbeans had saved by navigating to `<netbeans application directory>/var/filehistory`